# Arduino Leonardo USB device emulation

Tags: usb, arduino, hid, emulation

I recently got an Arduino Leonardo, and I'm fascinated by its ability to emulate USB HIDs.

But from what I can see, there are only libraries for keyboard and mouse emulation.

Is it possible to make it emulate a printer, microphone, headphones, anything other than a mouse or keyboard?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, assuming that the device is HID compliant.  You would just need to simulate the signals.

That said, it's unlikely that these other devices are HID compliant.  They might, however, be *[class-compliant.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_driver)*  Class-compliant means that you don't need special Windows drivers to plug it in and use it.  There are a number of devices that are class-compliant; [here is an example](http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/Oxygen61.html).

In the case of your Leonardo, it does not appear to be generally class-compliant, but more specifically HID compliant.  I suppose, however, that you could write a driver on the Leonardo to make it class-compliant (for some other class).

**See Also**
[USB Device Classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_serial_bus#Device_classes)

Comment: second link is 404

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LUFA toolchain](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php) to build much more than a few Leo examples.

Comment: Toolchain? Isn't it a library (USB stack)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to emulate any HID device with Arduino Leonardo, Pro Micro or their clones. It is not possible though with the [stock Arduino HID library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/HID) because it supports only SendReport method (Interrupt pipe), while generic HID support requires SetFeature/GetFeature methods (Control pipe).

Without going too deep into the theory of HID protocol implementation, you may check the emulation of the [HID-compliant UPS on Arduino](https://github.com/abratchik/HIDPowerDevice) and implement something similar for any device class.